# have div fadein on video "ended" only if it's the last in an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, binding, html5-video

Basically, it's what the question says. I need a div to fadeIn and another fadeOut (or show, I just used fadeIn) when a video ends, but only when it's the last video in an array of 6. I have

```
$("#myVid").bind("ended", function() {
            if(currentVideo == videos.length) {
                $(".control").fadeOut();
                $("#final").fadeIn();
            }
```

and I've tried

```
$("#myVid").bind("ended", function() {
            if(currentVideo == 6) {
                $(".control").fadeOut();
                $("#final").fadeIn();
            }
```

so, I should be doing it's job, but something isn't doing it, but I can't figure it out... Can I get some help here?

Comment: Tried `currentVideo == videos.length - 1` or `currentVideo == 5`. Arrays start at 0.

Comment: Can we see a bit of the html? Is myVid the id of the `<video/>` tag?

Comment: @ChristianVarga yeah, I messed that up, thanks, it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In an array of 6, the last item has the index 5 (index is zero-based). So if your `currentVideo` is an array index, you should `currentVideo == videos.length-1`. That's the only obvious mistake I noticed in your script.

Comment: okay, wow, I seem to keep forgetting that, but that was it. oops and thanks!